# React.js Scroll Threshold for Revealing Navigation

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Using React.js, another dev wrote this code to toggle the appearance of a navigation element called `ArticleNav`. It reveals itself as your scrolling down but hides itself when you scroll back up.

```
onScroll: function () {
  var mainColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('main-column')[0];
  var firstTextElement = mainColumn.querySelector('.dek');
  if (!firstTextElement) {
    firstTextElement = mainColumn.querySelector('.body-text');
  }

  if (window.scrollY >= firstTextElement.offsetTop) {
    if (!this.state.hideForArticleNav) {
      this.setState({hideForArticleNav: true});
    }
  } else {
    if (this.state.hideForArticleNav) {
      this.setState({hideForArticleNav: false});
    }
  }
}
```

This works great but the use of `if (window.scrollY >= firstTextElement.offsetTop)` makes this jump back and forth too rapidly and I wanted to create a, let's say..., 50px threshold to confirm that the user is actually scrolling in the opposite direction.

Do y'all have any recommendations on how to approach this? I am more jQuery-minded than React, so all of my normal fixes don't exactly translate here.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing part of your question.  Can't you simply add 50 px to the `firstTextElement.offsetTop`?

```
window.scrollY >= firstTextElement.offsetTop + 50
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a good setup to determine whether the user is scrolling up or down, so instead of setting `this.state.hideForArticleNav` you could set `this.state.lastDirectionChangeOffset` to the current window offset when the direction changes. Then you can check against that state value to see if it's +/- 50px.

```
onScroll: function () {
  var mainColumn = document.getElementsByClassName('main-column')[0];
  var firstTextElement = mainColumn.querySelector('.dek');
  if (!firstTextElement) {
    firstTextElement = mainColumn.querySelector('.body-text');
  }

  if (window.scrollY >= firstTextElement.offsetTop) {
    if (!this.state.hideForArticleNav) {
      this.setState({ lastDirectionChangeOffset: window.scrollY });
    }
  } else {
    if (this.state.hideForArticleNav) {
      this.setState({ lastDirectionChangeOffset: window.scrollY });
    }
  }

  if (window.scrollY > this.state.lastDirectionChangeOffset + 50) {
    this.setState({ hideForArticleNav: true })
  } else if (window.scrollY < this.state.lastDirectionChangeOffset - 50) {
    this.setState({ hideForArticleNav: false }) 
  }     
}
```